# Use a linear regression to calculate growth rate for many different entities in a DataFrame

Tags: pyspark, regression, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a DataFrame containing many thousands of entities which are measured over time and I need to calculate the growth over time of each entity and I am having trouble with the last step.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
    +------------+---------+-----------+
    |  monthYear |  entity |   count   |
    +------------+---------+-----------+
    | 2018_01    |   Foo   |       100 |
    | 2018_02    |   Foo   |       200 |
    | 2018_03    |   Foo   |       470 |
    | 2018_04    |   Foo   |       500 |
    | 2018_05    |   Foo   |       550 |
    | 2018_06    |   Foo   |       600 |
    | 2018_01    |   Bar   |       180 |
    | 2018_02    |   Bar   |       150 |
    | 2018_04    |   Bar   |       300 |
    +------------+---------+-----------+
```

Then my next step is to perform a pivot and fill all `null` elements with zero in order to create a full 6 month time series vector for each entity like so

```py
df = df.groupBy('entity').pivot('yearMonth').sum('count').na.fill(0)
```

which creates

```
    +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |  entity |2018_01|2018_02|2018_03|2018_04|2018_05|2018_06|
    +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |   Foo   |  100  |  200  |  470  |  500  |  550  |  600  |
    |   Bar   |  180  |  150  |   0   |  300  |   0   |   0   |
    +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

After that I un-pivot the data, apply `VectorAssembler` and cast the labels to `DoubleType`.

```py
df = df.selectExpr("entity",
 "stack(6,'1',2018_01,'2',2018_02,'3',2018_03,'4',2018_04,'5',2018_05,'6',
2018_06) as (label_string,count)")

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['count'], outputCol='features')
df = assembler.transform(df)

df = df.withColumn('label', df['label_string'].cast(DoubleType())).select('entity','label','features')
```

So my final DataFrame looks like this

```
    +---------+---------+-----------+
    |  entity |  label  |  features |
    +---------+---------+-----------+
    |   Foo   |  1.0    |    [100]  |
    |   Foo   |  2.0    |    [200]  |
    |   Foo   |  3.0    |    [470]  |
    |   Foo   |  4.0    |    [500]  |
    |   Foo   |  5.0    |    [550]  |
    |   Foo   |  6.0    |    [600]  |
    |   Bar   |  1.0    |    [180]  |
    |   Bar   |  2.0    |    [150]  |
    |   Bar   |  3.0    |     [0]   |
    |   Bar   |  4.0    |    [300]  |
    |   Bar   |  5.0    |     [0]   |
    |   Bar   |  6.0    |     [0]   |
    +---------+---------+-----------+
```

Now I want to apply Spark ML's `LinearRegression` to the time series for each entity and save the gradient of the resulting line. What is the best way to do this operation efficiently?

Also this is my first time attempting a (simple) machine learning task with PySpark so please let me know if there is a better way to do any of the above steps.

**Additional thought:**
*I've been looking around and it's starting to seem like there is no good way to do this, so would it be better for me to reformat the feature column so that each row contains an array of the whole time series and then apply something from sklearn?
e.g.*

```
    +---------+----------------------------+
    |  entity |         features           |
    +---------+----------------------------+
    |   Foo   |  [100,200,470,500,550,600] |
    |   Bar   |  [180,150,0,300,0,0]       |
    +---------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: It is locked to 24 (corresponding to 24 months)